# C# WCF returning parameters with/without REF/OUT

Tags: c#, wcf, out, ref

Following is a SIMPLIFIED VERSION of my WCF service code. This code works fine and returns me the data.

My question is this only works if I pass the customers object either by ref or by out. If I modify the entire code so as to pass customers object WITHOUT ref or out the count in i variable is 0.

If List is a reference variable why does this work with ref/out and does not work without ref/out.

Also please note that I will not be able to return a value from the method as I have to return multiple values.

**Client Code:**

```
List<Customer> customers = null;
ClientProxy proxy = new ClientProxy();
proxy.GetCustomers(ref customers);
int i = customers.Count;
```

**Service Proxy:**

```
public class ClientProxy
{
    public void GetCustomers(ref List<Customer> customers)
    {
        INWGetCustomers proxy = new ChannelFactory<INWGetCustomers>("netNamedPipeBinding").CreateChannel();
        proxy.GetCustomers(ref customers);
    }
}
```

**Service Contract & Data Contract:**

```
[DataContract]
public class Customer
{
    [DataMember]
    public System.String CustomerId;

    [DataMember]
    public System.String CompanyName;
}

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://www.temp.com")]
public interface INWGetCustomers
{
    [OperationContract()]
    void GetCustomers(ref List<Customer> customers);
}
```

**Service Code:**

```
public class NWGetCustomersService : INWGetCustomers
{
    public void GetCustomers(ref List<Customer> customers)
    {
        customers = new List<Customer>();
        customers.Add(new Customer() { CustomerId = "1", CompanyName = "A" });
        customers.Add(new Customer() { CustomerId = "2", CompanyName = "B" });
        customers.Add(new Customer() { CustomerId = "3", CompanyName = "C" });
        customers.Add(new Customer() { CustomerId = "4", CompanyName = "D" });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because using ref or out in this context forces to treat list as output parameter. It is not real passing by reference because the object is send fbetween server and client. If you look at WSDL you will see how .NET is generating this code

To sum up: it is not same object on client and on server, so it does not matter that list is a reference variable

Answer (score 0):

Always we have to keep in mind that the reference to the object is passed by value. When calling a method it would have its own copy of reference value. If reference value changes inside the method it won’t get reflected in the outer variable. (I mean if new instance is created and the relevant reference value is assigned to the method variable then it won’t get updated to the outer variable). That is why you have to add ref in your method. Execute the below code snippet. Then modify the code with ref key word added in method signature and in caller as well. You can realize the difference.

```
namespace ParameterSample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Customer customer = null;
            GetValue(customer);
            Console.WriteLine("In Main Method : Is customer Null? >>  " + (customer == null));
            Console.Read();
        }
        public static void GetValue(Customer customer)
        {
            customer = new Customer();
            Console.WriteLine("Inside GetValue Method : Is customer Null ? >>  " + (customer == null));
        }
    }
    class Customer
    { }
}
```

Comment: What you are talking about is true in case of call to a method with in the same process and I do understand the role of REF in this case. What confused me was the the role of REF/OUT when the method is called over WCF.

Comment: The purpose/concept doesn’t change, it is not a force and it is a MUST.#3 line of Question says: “If List is a reference variable why does this work with ref/out and does not work without ref/out.”The focus area is, understanding the difference between “reference variable” and “Pass by reference”. Thought might lead that Reference variables are passed by reference. It is wrong. It is passed by value only to any method without REF keyword. The outer variable and method variable are different variables in the stack. When calling a method the value is copied to the method variable.

Comment: 1) You are passing to the method “customer” variable with null value assigned.  
2) Factory Patterns are to create object. The Generic factory class “ChannelFactory<TChannel>” takes care of creating the object at the client end.
3) Once the object is created by the factory, the reference value of the object is assigned to the method’s parameter “customer” variable and not to the outer variable.
4) The understanding needs to be of where the object is created. If we need to access the same object created inside a method to the outer variable then we have to go ahead with REF/OUT.

Comment: The question does not talk about/related to WCF even though the code is for WCF. If your doubt is clarified go ahead enjoying the fun with code.

Comment: Again I completely agree with you on what you are saying. And thank you for the elaborate explanation of the ChannelFactory<TChannel>. 
But I have to reiterate that probably I might not have mentioned the word WCF, but my entire code is related to WCF. So my question also was related to the behavior of passing variable across process.